# Problem Accessing UNIX sockets remotely via SSH tunnel

Tags: rhel, mysql, sshd, port-forwarding, unix-sockets

I'm trying to use a TCP port to connect to a MySQL unix domain socket on a remote machine. I have removed networking on the mySQL server to harden it.

The SSH tunnel looks like this:

MyPC <-------------> Linux Server 1 <-----> Linux Server 2 (MySQL DB)

Step 1) SSH From MyPC to Linux server 1 using TCP port 3088 for local and remote ports.

Step 2) From Linux server 1 SSH to Linux server 2 using local TCP port 3088 and target socket /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

example command:

- ssh  -L localhost:3088:/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock -vv
  userName@10.10.10.134

The issue occurs when I try and access the MySQL DB via the client on MyPC. The client is unable to connect to the DB and in the terminal session I get the following error messages:

> debug1: Connection to port 3088 forwarding to
> /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock port -2 requested.
>
> debug2: fd 11 setting O_NONBLOCK debug1: channel 3: new
> [direct-streamlocal@openssh.com]
>
> channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
>
> debug2: channel 3: zombie
>
> debug2: channel 3: garbage collecting
>
> debug1: channel 3: free: direct-streamlocal@openssh.com: listening
> port 3088 for  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock port -2, connect from
> 127.0.0.1 port 60358 to 127.0.0.1 port 3088, nchannels 4

I have validated the socket is correct and I can access the DB locally on Linux server 2 using the socket file.

Before I disabled networking on MySQL (my.cnf: skip-networking) I could connect to the server using port 3306 instead with this example command on Linux Server 1:

- ssh -L 3088:localhost:3306  userName@10.10.10.134

Below is the sshd_config file on Linux 2:

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.80 2008/07/02 02:24:18 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options change a
# default value.

Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 MACs hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any AddressFamily inet
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# Disable legacy (protocol version 1) support in the server for new
# installations. In future the default will change to require explicit
# activation of protocol 1 Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO LogLevel VERBOSE

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes PermitRootLogin no
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no PasswordAuthentication yes

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no GSSAPIAuthentication yes
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing, 
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will 
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no UsePAM yes

# Accept locale-related environment variables AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#AllowStreamLocalForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes X11UseLocalhost no
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0 ClientAliveInterval 300
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
#UseDNS yes UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none

# no default banner path Banner /etc/issue

Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 MACs hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1

# override default of no subsystems Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

I did try enabling AllowTcpForwarding yes/any and restart sshd but this did not change the behavior. As well, before I disabled networking on MySQL (my.cnf: skip-networking) I could connect to the server using port 3306 instead with this example command on Linux Server 1:

- ssh -L 3088:localhost:3306  userName@10.10.10.134

Adding some debug output of a successful authentication to Linux Server 2 and then later we see the error message once the MySQL client tryies to connect to the MySql server via the tunnel:

```
ssh  -L localhost:3088:/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock -vv userName@10.10.10.134
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "10.10.10.134" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.10.134 [10.10.10.134] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userName/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userName/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userName/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userName/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userName/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userName/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.10.10.134:22 as 'userName'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<8192<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 4090/8192
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '10.10.10.134' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/userName/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 4061/8192
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/userName/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/userName/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/userName/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:2085)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:2085)

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/userName/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/userName/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/userName/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
userName@10.10.10.134's password: 
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 10.10.10.134 ([10.10.10.134]:22).
debug1: Local connections to localhost:3088 forwarded to remote address /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock:-2
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 3088.
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 3088.
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 2: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 4 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 2
debug2: channel 2: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_CA.UTF-8
debug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 2: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 2: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 2
debug2: channel 2: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 2
```

### MySQL Client connects (eg. MySQL workbench)

```
  debug1: Connection to port 3088 forwarding to /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock port -2 requested.
    debug2: fd 10 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: channel 3: new [direct-streamlocal@openssh.com]
    channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
    debug2: channel 3: zombie
    debug2: channel 3: garbage collecting
    debug1: channel 3: free: direct-streamlocal@openssh.com: listening port 3088 for /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock port -2, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 33034 to 127.0.0.1 port 3088, nchannels 4
```

Appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Are you using key-based authentication? Is the key (in `authorized_keys` on the target server) specified with options like `restrict`, `permitopen` and/or such?

Comment: No I'm not using key-based authentication it is using a 2FA. As well, if I change the config of the MySQL server to enable TCP 3306 instead of strictly using the Unix domain socket /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock then I can access the MySQL server without issue. It is only when I try using the Unix domain socket that i have issues i.e. issue with this command "ssh -L localhost:3088:/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock -vv userName@10.10.10.134" but no issue with this command "ssh -L 3088:localhost:3306 userName@10.10.10.134".